# Pandas cumsum only if positive else zero

Tags: pandas

I am making a table, where i want to show that if there's no income, no expense can happen
it's a cumulative sum table

This is what I've

| Incoming | Outgoing | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 150 | -150 |
| 10 | 20 | -160 |
| 100 | 30 | -90 |
| 50 | 70 | -110 |

---

Required output

| Incoming | Outgoing | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 150 | 0 |
| 10 | 20 | 0 |
| 100 | 30 | 70 |
| 50 | 70 | 50 |

---

I've tried

```
df.clip(lower=0)
```

and

```
df['new_column'].apply(lambda x : df['outgoing']-df['incoming'] if df['incoming']>df['outgoing'])
```

That doesn't work as well

is there any other way?

Comment: Hi, since you're new, please always post a reproducable example and some code you tried with each questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

A more straightforward approach inspired by your code using `clip` and without `numpy`:

```
diff = df['Incoming'].sub(df['Outgoing'])
df['Total'] = diff.mul(diff.ge(0).cumsum().clip(0, 1)).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output:
   Incoming  Outgoing  Total
0         0       150      0
1        10        20      0
2       100        30     70
3        50        70     50
```

---

Old answer:

Find the row where the balance is positive for the first time then compute the cumulative sum from this point:

```
start = np.where(df['Incoming'] - df['Outgoing'] >= 0)[0][0]

df['Total'] = df.iloc[start:]['Incoming'].sub(df.iloc[start:]['Outgoing']) \
                .cumsum().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Incoming  Outgoing  Total
0         0       150      0
1        10        20      0
2       100        30     70
3        50        70     50
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can check when Incoming  is greater than Outgoing using `np.where` and assign a helper column. Then you can check when this new column is not null, using `notnull()`, calculate the difference, and use `cumsum()` on the result:

```
df['t'] = np.where(df['Incoming'].ge(df['Outgoing']),0,np.nan)
df['t'].ffill(axis=0,inplace=True)

df['Total'] = np.where(df['t'].notnull(),(df['Incoming'].sub(df['Outgoing'])),df['t'])
df['Total'] = df['Total'].cumsum()

df.drop('t',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

This will give back:

```
   Incoming  Outgoing  Total
0         0       150    NaN
1        10        20    NaN
2       100        30   70.0
3        50        70   50.0
```