# Vectorize an iterative algorithm in Pandas. Tried clip, cumsum, ge, diff and all of their combination without any luck so far :)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compute the investment of the trades that happened between two dates (and discard any amount that was on the account before that - which is why it's different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243569/pandas-cumsum-only-if-positive-else-zero/70243946) where they only consider if the result of a given trade is positive or negative).

So typically I have this situation (3 first columns) and instead of the "Sell" column I want the "Sell adjusted":

| Time t | Buy | Sell | Desired adjusted value for Sell and explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 (we didn't buy anything yet) |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 (same above) |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 (we are buying so 0) |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 (we are buying so 0) |
| 4 | 0 | 7 | 5 (Here, we bought 5 so far, so we can't sell more than that) |
| 5 | 9 | 0 | 0 (we are buying so 0) |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 2 (We currently have 9 on the account, so we can sell 2) |
| 7 | 0 | 11 | 7 (We now have 7, so that's the max we can sell) |
| 8 | 0 | 2 | 0 (We have now 0, we can't sell anything) |

I have an iterative version, but it takes an awful amount of time to compute and I can't find a good way to vectorize it and that drives me crazy:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'nb_bought': [0,0,2,3,0,9,0,0,0], 'nb_sold': [1,2,0,0,7,0,2,11,2]})
cur_amount = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   nb_bought = int(row["nb_bought"])
   nb_sold = int(row["nb_sold"])
   if nb_bought > 0:
      cur_amount += nb_bought
      df.at[index,"nb_sold_adjusted"] = 0
   elif nb_sold > 0:
      if nb_sold >= cur_amount:
         df.at[index,"nb_sold_adjusted"] = cur_amount
         cur_amount = 0
      else:
         df.at[index,"nb_sold_adjusted"] = nb_sold
         cur_amount -= nb_sold
```

```
> $ python3 -i tmp.py
>>> df
   time  nb_bought  nb_sold  nb_sold_adjusted
0     0          0        1               0.0
1     1          0        2               0.0
2     2          2        0               0.0
3     3          3        0               0.0
4     4          0        7               5.0
5     5          9        0               0.0
6     6          0        2               2.0
7     7          0       11               7.0
8     8          0        2               0.0
```

Comment: `df.nb_bought.cumsum() & df.nb_sold`  actually gets part of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a vectorized approach for this since you need to reset a cumulative value in the middle. But there could be some ways to improve performance. e.g. don't use `iterrows` which can be slow, just use `zip` with a plain for loop; and using a plain list to build up the result and then assigning to a data frame is also recommended for performance:

```
inventory = 0
adjusted_sell = []

for buy, sell in zip(df.nb_bought, df.nb_sold):
    inventory += buy
    adjusted_sell.append(min(inventory, sell))  # sell the minimum of inventory and sell
    inventory = max(0, inventory - sell)  # reset inventory or current amount if remaining < 0

df['nb_sold_adjusted'] = adjusted_sell
df
   time  nb_bought  nb_sold  nb_sold_adjusted
0     0          0        1                 0
1     1          0        2                 0
2     2          2        0                 0
3     3          3        0                 0
4     4          0        7                 5
5     5          9        0                 0
6     6          0        2                 2
7     7          0       11                 7
8     8          0        2                 0
```